# DB2 query - selecting specific duplicated records

Tags: db2

I am pretty new to dealing with DB2 - on an IBM AS400.

I ran the following query :

```
SELECT *                                                         
FROM mytable
WHERE ID = 1963003909
```

This is the results of the query:

```
     ID    WK END DT  VRSN    AMT  
 -----------  ----------  ------  ------------  
  1963003909  2012-03-24       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-03-31       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-04-07       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-04-14       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-04-21       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-04-28       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-05-05       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-05-12       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-05-19       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-05-26       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-06-02       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-06-09       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-06-16       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-06-23       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-06-30       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-07-07       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-07-14       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-07-21       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-07-28       1          0.00  
  1963003909  2012-07-28       2        320.00
```

I want to be able to modify the query to select only the records with the maximum in the VRSN column to be able to put the information into a report.

I have tried to read other examples from this site, but couldn't find anything that wasn't showing how to delete duplicate records from the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't have DB2 in front of me now, but you should be able to order by `vrsn` using an [OLAP function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html) (ANSI SQL calls them *window functions*) such as `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then select based on your ordering. Start with something like this:

```
with data(<column_list>, Ranking) as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY vrsn desc) as Ranking
from mytable
)
select * from data where Ranking = 1
```

Basically, DB2 will assign number 1 to the row with the highest `vrsn` for every `id`, and on and on, and different OLAP functions will break ties in `vrsn` in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for your information.  Like I mentioned in the original post, I'm pretty new at DB2, so a lot of what you put in your reply is over my head.

Answer (score 1):

See if this will work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM mylibrary.mytable
WHERE ID = 1963003909 AND VRSN = (SELECT MAX(VRSN) FROM mylibrary.mytable)
```

You didn't show a library name in your example but I have.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to run that query and I didn't get any results.  I ended up taking the easy way out and modified the query to put the VRSN descending, then store the ID and Week end date in a separate storage field and check the fields compared to the query fields.  If the fields are equal, I skip moving the row to my report.  Thanks again though.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message? I ran that exact query on an AS/400 I have here and it worked - I ran it against a different table with different data than yours but all I changed was column names...